# how to use builtins.input for multiple inputs

Tags: python, unit-testing

In my unittest, I have 2 prompts in the test.  I am trying to use 2 `@patch("builtins.input")`, but it seems to only take the 1 of the return values.

```
@patch("builtins.input")
@patch("builtins.input")
def test_setProfileName_modify_init_prompt_empty(self, paramName1, paramName2):
    paramName1.return_value = self.profileName_prod
    paramName2.return_value = self.profileName_dev


    a = c.ALMConfig(self.configType)
    self.assertTrue(a.setProfileName())
    self.assertEqual(a.getProfileName(), self.profileName_dev)
    self.assertEqual(a.profileName, self.profileName_dev)


    self.assertTrue(a.setProfileName())
    self.assertEqual(a.getProfileName(), self.profileName_prod)
    self.assertEqual(a.profileName, self.profileName_prod)
```

The call `a.setProfileName()` will prompt for 1 input using `input()` call in my function. In this test, it will call `a.setProfileName()` twice.

- First time I call `a.setProfileName()`, I would enter the value of `self.profileName_prod`.
- The second time I call it, I would enter the value of `self.profileName_dev`.

But the test fails after the second `a.setProfileName()` case (at the second to last `assertEqual` after the second `a.setProfileName()` call).

```
    self.assertEqual(a.getProfileName(), self.profileName_prod)
```

The reason for the failure is because `a.getProfileName` is returning the value for `self.profileName_dev` instead of `self.profileName_prod`.

I had tested my code in the python cli to make sure the behavior is correct.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: You can't patch the same thing twice. Instead, make the patch object return the first value and then the second on successive calls.

Comment: `setProfileName` should take an argument; let code closer to the "edge" of your program be responsible for getting input from the user. The less I/O in your code, the better.

Comment: That is, prefer the equivalent of `a.setProfileName(input())` to `def setProfileName(self): x = input(); ...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patching the same function twice does not make it return different values on different calls. You can use the `side_effect` attribute of the `Mock` object by setting it with a list of values you want the function to return in successive calls instead:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
@patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['dev', 'prod'])
def test_input(mock_input):
    assert input() == 'dev'
    assert input() == 'prod'
test_input() # this will not raise an exception since all assertions are True
```

Comment: Thanks blhsing.  The objective of my test would be to make sure the behavior of the function handles the input properly.  If I mock it, it would not be a real test of the function.

Comment: My suggested solution is no different from your attempted solution in terms of what's being mocked. That is, in both of our solutions it is only the built-in `input` function that is mocked, so I don't see how you find it concerning that the built-in `input` function is mocked in my solution.

Comment: My bad, blhsing.  I was not clear how `side_effect` worked and misunderstood what it was doing.  I tested your solution with my code, and it works!  Much more elegant.  thanks!    Updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I revisited blhsing's solution, and it is more much elegant.  Here is my working test code now:

```
@patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['dev', 'production'])
def test_setProfileName_modify_init_prompt_update_new(self, paramName):
    a = c.ALMConfig(self.configType)
    self.assertTrue(a.setProfileName())
    self.assertEqual(a.getProfileName(), self.profileName_dev)
    self.assertEqual(a.profileName, self.profileName_dev)


    self.assertEqual(a.getProfileName(), self.profileName_dev)
    self.assertTrue(a.setProfileName())
    self.assertEqual(a.getProfileName(), self.profileName_prod)
    self.assertEqual(a.profileName, self.profileName_prod)
```

Thanks everyone for your comments! :)

Answer (score 1):

To provide a more simple and to the point answer for anyone visiting this in 2020 and later, you can just do

```
`with patch("builtins.input", return_value = "Whatever you want returned"):
   self.assertEqual("<Object>", "Whatever you want returned")
`
```

in python 3.8 in later.

To see a full easy to follow example keep reading otherwise stop here.

**Full Example:**
The below code shows a full example of this with a class named "AnsweredQuestion" and with a unit test

```
`class AnsweredQuestion:
   def __init__(self):
     print("I hope you find this example helpful")
   
   def get_input(self):
     print("Enter your input")
     entered_data = input()
     print("You entered '" + entered_data + "'")
     return get_input
`
```

**Unit Test to test above class `AnsweredQuestion`**

```
`
import builtins
import unittest
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
# Assuming a directory named "answers" in your setup
import answers
from answers import AnsweredQuestion
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

class TestAnsweredQuestion(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_get_input(self):
    with patch("builtins.input", return_value = "Thanks. This is correct"):
      self.assertEqual(AnsweredQuestion.get_input(), "Thanks this is correct")


if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
`
```

Comment: Glad to see you posting answers to old questions! Do keep in mind that you are expected to add some details about what you fixed or why it is right. It helps users understand what is going on, rather than just being served the answer. Consider it a rule for all your answers here. I hope you have a good time.